# Firefox: show the menu bar for all users by default

Tags: linux, firefox

I'd like to make the menu bar in **Firefox Quantum 62.0** always visible, system-wide, for all users, out of the box. I didn't manage to find any workable solution, no preferences (`about:config`) either.

Making a copy of `.mozilla` directory under `/etc/skel` is not a workable solution in my view as you might run into other issues with updates, extensions etc. and it means lots of unnecessary garbage.

The OS is Linux 64 bit (although I don't think it's relevant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the menu bar by default for all users, set the following [policy](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#displaymenubar) in `/path/to/firefox_dir/distribution/policies.json`:

```
{
  "policies": {
    "DisplayMenuBar": true
  }
}
```

Optionally, replicating the disabled Alt-key focus functionality when the menu bar is shown can be done globally through [AutoConfig](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig#w_setting-up-autoconfig) by setting the contents of `/path/to/firefox_dir/defaults/pref/autoconfig.js` to:

```
pref("general.config.filename", "firefox.cfg");
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
```

and ensuring `/path/to/firefox_dir/firefox.cfg` contains

```
defaultPref("ui.key.menuAccessKeyFocuses", false);
```

along with a comment (`// ...`) on the first line.